# Comprobar si un objeto es cualquier tipo de número

Tags: python, python-3.x, objeto

Tengo en Python una lista de números de cualquier tipo: `int`, `float`, `complex`, `Decimal` y `Fraction`. Por ejemplo:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from fractions import Fraction

lista_numeros = [2, 2.0, Decimal('2.0'), complex(2,0), Fraction(2,1)]
```

Me gustaría saber cómo se puede comprobar (de manera *pythónica*) que cada objeto sea un número sin necesidad de tener que comprobar para cada uno de ellos si es una instancia de alguno de todos esos tipos posibles.

```
for numero in lista_numeros:
    print("{}: {}".format(numero, isinstance(numero, (int, tuple, complex, Decimal, Fraction))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Python existe una clase abstracta dentro del módulo [`numbers`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/numbers.html#module-numbers) llamada [`Number`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/numbers.html#numbers.Number), que representa la raíz de toda la jerarquía de números. Por lo tanto, cualquier objeto de tipo número está instanciado a partir de una clase que implementa `Number` o alguna subclase de `Number`.

Una solución sería la siguiente:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from fractions import Fraction
from numbers import Number

lista_numeros = [2, 2.0, Decimal('2.0'), complex(2,0), Fraction(2,1), '2', True]

for numero in lista_numeros:
    print("{} ({}): {}".format(numero, type(numero).__name__, isinstance(numero, Number)))
```

Dando como resultado:

> ```
> 2 (int): True
> 2.0 (float): True
> 2.0 (Decimal): True
> (2+0j) (complex): True
> 2 (Fraction): True
> 2 (str): False
> True (bool): True
> ```

Hay que tener en cuenta que Python considera el tipo `bool` como numérico, dando a `False` el valor `0` y a `True` el valor `1`.

---

*Entrada de SOen de donde se ha obtenido gran parte de la información: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441358/python-most-pythonic-way-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-number*